# APFS Sparse Bundle Encrypted images on HFS+ HDD

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, apfs, hfs+, sparsebundle

macOS is no longer allowing me to use HFS+ encrypted for external disks. Is it safe to create a 20TB encrypted sparse bundle disk image on a HFS+ formatted mechanical hard drive?

If so, can I use APFS encrypted or should I keep HFS+ encrypted? — I can't confirm using APFS encrypted disk images on a HFS+ mechanical hard drive will remove the drawbacks of using APFS on mechanical disks.

Comment: If your macOS is no longer allowing you to use HFS+ encrypted for external disks, then you macOS will also no longer allow to use HFS+ encrypted for disk images. However, you can still encrypted the sparse bundle disk image.